# How to decorate a specific type in Autofac?

Tags: c#, autofac

I have a command like this:

```
public class EditComplaintCommandHandler : IHandleCommand<EditComplaintCommand>
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public EditComplaintCommandHandler(
        IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public void Handle(EditComplaintCommand command)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Now I only want to decorate this command. Here's my decorator:

```
public class MySpecificCommandDecorator : IHandleCommand<EditComplaintCommand>
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public MySpecificCommandDecorator(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public void Handle(EditComplaintCommand command)
    {
       // do something
    }
}
```

So I want that `MySpecificCommandDecorator` only decorates `EditComplaintCommandHandler`.

I've tried:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
       .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IHandleCommand<>))
       .Named("handler", typeof(IHandleCommand<>));

builder.Register(c => new MySpecificCommandDecorator(c.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>()))
       .As<IHandleCommand<EditComplaintCommand>>();
```

but this doesn't work off course, since I didn't register it as a decorator.

How can I only decorate `EditComplaintCommandHandler` with `MySpecificCommandDecorator` using Autofac?

Comment: When resolve using: `container.Resolve<IHandleCommand<EditComplaintCommand>>();`. It resolves the `MySpecificCommandDecorator`. Because you override it with your custom registration. So what is actually not working?

Comment: @MartijnvanPut It indeed resolves the `MySpecificCommandDecorator`, but it doesn't decorate `IHandleCommand<EditComplaintCommand>`

Comment: did you check using the `RegisterDecorator` command with Autofac? You can register a `IHandleCommand<EditComplaintCommand>` with the `MySpecificCommandDecorator`. http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/adapters-decorators.html